# How to add N blank lines between all rows of a text file?

Tags: awk, sed, tail

I have a file that looks

```
a
b
c
d
```

Suppose I want to add N lines (in the example 3, but I actually need 20 or 100 depending on the file)

```
a


b


c


d
```

I can add one blank line between all of them with sed

```
sed -i '0~1 a\\' file
```

But `sed -i '0~3 a\\' file` inserts one line every 3 rows.

Comment: `sed -e 'G;G;G' file`?

Comment: It works perfectly, a bit messy when various lines must be added, thanks :)

Comment: I [added a more dynamic awk solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58754946/3832970).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use with GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i 'G;G;G' file
```

The `G;G;G` will append three empty lines below each non-final line.

Or, `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\n\n\n"};1'
```

See an [online `sed` and `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/NOSJXt).

If you need to set the number of newlines dynamically use

```
nl="
"
awk -v nl="$nl" 'BEGIN{for(c=0;c<3;c++) v=v""nl;ORS=v};1' file > newfile
```

Comment: shorter with `awk -v ORS='\n\n\n' 1`

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace -v lines=3 '{print; for(i=0;i<lines;i++) print ""}' file
```

Update with Ed's hints (see comments):

```
awk -i inplace -v lines=3 '{print; for(i=1;i<=lines;i++) print ""}' file
```

Update (without trailing empty lines):

```
awk -i inplace -v lines=3 'NR==1; NR>1{for(i=1;i<=lines;i++) print ""; print}' file
```

Output to `file`:

```
a



b



c



d
```

Comment: The loop should start `for (i=1`, not `for (i=0`.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thank you. I have removed `=` to fix this bug.

Comment: I see you changed the end condition rather than the starting value. In awk everything starts at 1, not 0. That includes line numbers, field numbers, array indices, and string character positions. So, idiomatically and to avoid tripping over it unexpectedly later, you should avoid starting loops or hand-created arrays or anything else at 0 and start at 1 instead to fit in with the way awk does everything else.

Comment: @EdMorton: I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` and corutils:

```
N=4
sed "\$b;$(yes G\; | head -n$N)" infile
```

Similar trick with `awk`:

```
N=4
awk 1 RS="$(yes \\n | head -n$N | tr -d '\n')" infile
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;G;s/\n/&/2;Ta' file
```

This will add 2 blank lines following each line.

Change 2 to what ever number you desire between each line.

An alternative (more efficient?):

```
sed '1{x;:a;/^.\{2\}/!s/^/\n/;ta;s/.//;x};G' file
```